# Where do I ask a question about a tool that affects Stack Exchange functionality?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

I asked another [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286380/691711) about configuring NoScript to allow the Stack Overflow feature, Runnable Snippets, through the XSS filtering feature of NoScript.  So far I have gotten several down votes, but I'm not sure if it's because it is off-topic, or whether it's outside of the meta scope.

Since this is a question about how to use a tool in a proper manner, does it belong on Super User?  However, since this question pertains directly to site structure and allowing a feature set to be used with an existing tool, should it be asked on meta since it deals with URL structure of the site?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Questions pertaining to how to configure a browser extension such as NoScript are on topic at [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Super User even has a [NoScript tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/noscript) with 46 questions.

As I commented on your other question, I believe the downvotes are related to the fact that meta.SO is for questions about SO related topics, and your question is basically asking for a regex to configure a plugin.